# How does one provide sudo file read access privileges to a Wine application?

Tags: wine, setcap

In accordance with best practices I desire not to run Wine as root, http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ  I see plenty of examples for use of setcap for networking, but not so much for file read access.

Essentially, I'm trying to give an application the capability to read all files and subdirectories with at least the following privs:
-r-------- 1 root root

I've tried using built in search, but it fails.  A file exists with the particular string I'm interested in, but I don't recall its filename or directory located so I intend to use PowerGREP to locate it, but files owned by root are not readily readable via apps spawned in Wine without enhancement by something like setcap.

Answer (score 0):

you can try CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH capabilty while doing setcap. Which will eventually allow your appication to read all the files of any user